# Programmatically use navigation properties in EF given the foreignkey

Tags: entity-framework, reflection, navigation-properties

In my project I have `EF with ADO.NET`. Suppose I have in `Entity Framework` the following classes

```
class Product
{
   int Id { get; set;}
   string Name { get; set; }
   int TypeId { get; set; }
   int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

class Type
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have the `navigation properties`:

1. **hasCategory: from Category(Id) to Product(CategoryId), 1 to Many**
2. **hasType: from Type(Id) to Product(TypeId), 1 to Many**

Therefore if I want to access a specific category name or type name of a product (given the context):

```
int productId = 1;
var categoryName = context.Products.Single(p => p.Id == productId).hasCategory.Name;
var typeName = context.Products.Single(p => p.Id == productId).hasType.Name;
```

Now if I have the property name I can get the property:

```
string propertyName = "CategoryId";
var propertyValue = GetType(Product).GetProperty(propertyName)
```

Given the `propertyName` I want to know if there is any way to get the matching navigation property (either `hasCategory` or `hasType`) in order to get the name. Oterhwise I do not know in which of the two classes `Category` and `Type` I should look for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying in the opposite direction?

Attached objects receive dinamically a "RelationshipManager" property. It fournish a useful method GetAllRelatedEnds() that returns a collection of "RelatedEnd", where you can find for example the relationship name.

```
Object myObj;
var q = myObj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(RelationshipManager)).First();
RelationshipManager rm = q.GetValue(myObj, null) as RelationshipManager;
foreach (RelatedEnd re in rm.GetAllRelatedEnds())
{
    // Here you get the "other-side" objects
}
```

Nevertheless, the name of the navigation property remains private :( 
Hope this approaches somebody to the solution